# ggplot2- Extending a geom_segment beyond visible range of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I am building a plot for a shiny app using ggplot and plotly. My data spans years, but the user is able to control the date range and just view a small amount at a time. I am trying to use geom_segments to represent durations of events(events with start and end dates). My problem is that the event will not show up on the plot at all unless both the start and end dates are within the user's selected view range.

Is there a way to make the geom_segments appear and look like they are continuing off the side of the plot if, for example, the xend date is not in the selected view range?

Thanks!

Update: 
Using coord_cartesian instead seems to be the right track but now I am getting this view:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inLdC.png)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `coord_cartesian` function to limit your plots but still keep the lines drawn...

```
df2 <- expand.grid(
    lineend = c('round', 'butt', 'square'),
    linejoin = c('round', 'mitre', 'bevel'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df2 <- data.frame(df2, y = 1:9)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = 1, y = y, xend = 2, yend = y, label = paste(lineend, linejoin))) +
    geom_segment(
        lineend = df2$lineend, linejoin = df2$linejoin,
        size = 3, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "inches"))
    ) +
    geom_text(hjust = 'outside', nudge_x = -0.2) +
    # scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.5,1.5)) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0.5,1.5))
```

So remove the `#` from the `scale_x_continuous` to see the difference.

Comment: Ohhh ok I see! Thanks! Is there something I might need to change beforehand becuse I'm working with dates? Strangely the plot is now squeezing the x axis markers so close together that you can't even see what's going on, and the plot is still the same size- all the data is just squeezed to the middle. I'll try to upload a picture... not sure how to do that but i'll try!

Comment: Actually, problem solved! When I passed ggplot into plotly I had layout(xaxis = list(autorange=TRUE)). I removed that and it's perfect! Thanks!